# Camera Button Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an app that allows users to take selfies and upload it to Facebook, but the `selfieTapped` button I created is not working. It brings up a black screen. It does not let the user pick a photo from their library nor does it allow the user to take a picture.

```
import UIKit
import Social

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func selfieTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        //this method will be called when the user has taken a photo or has selected a photo from the photo library
        func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {

            //takes the image parameter and displays it inside myImageView
            myImageView.image = image

            //hides the imagePicker and animates the transition
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }

        //creates a new UIImagePickerController and sets it to the imagePicker variable
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        //self the imagePicker's delegate property to the current view controller
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        //sets the imagePicker's sourceType property to .Camera
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {

            //checking if a front camera is available
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

            //if so, set it to the front camera
            if (UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.Front)) {

                //setting it to the front camera
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = .Front

            } else {

                //setting it to the rear camera if the front is not available
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = .Rear
            }

        } else {

            //if the camera is not available, the photo library will be shown
            imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        }

        //presents the imagePicker modally, sliding it up from the bottom of the screen and it animates the transition
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func shareTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        //sets the serviceType property to Facebook
        let facebookSocial = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

        //myImageView image is added to the Facebook post
        facebookSocial.addImage(myImageView.image)

        //it is displayed and uses animation
        self.presentViewController(facebookSocial, animated: true, completion: nil)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have closed `Camera` & `Photos` permission for your app in `Setting`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cause of the trouble, but it certainly will be trouble later: you've put one function inside of another:

```
@IBAction func selfieTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
```

Don't do that. They both need to be at the same level, as methods of your class. Otherwise, `didFinishPickingImage` can never be called.

Comment: I took it outside the function and it works perfect. I don't know if it actually fixed the problem, but it definitely works.

Comment: It would have given you trouble later, _after_ you solved the actual problem in the question! :)